# Sendgrid import issue in Meteor

Tags: meteor, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to use `sendgrid` npm package in Meteor (on the server):

```
const sendgridMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
```

Keep getting this error:

```
(STDERR) packages\modules.js:961
(STDERR) const {
(STDERR)       ^
(STDERR)
(STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
(STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
(STDERR)     at D:\myProject\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:331:30
(STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
(STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

**Update:** `package.json` includes the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/client": "^6.1.4",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.1.4",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "card": "^2.3.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^0.10.0",
    "googleapis": "^21.3.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "pnotify": "^3.2.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.3.1",
    "stripe": "^4.24.0"
}
```

Comment: Show your `package.json`, please.

Comment: And, just to be sure, when you remove this `require()`, the error is disappearing, right?

Comment: yes, with the require() removed, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `SendGrid SDK v6` [requires Node.js version 6 and higher](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/mail#prerequisites), but the one bundled in Meteor is `4.8.4`:

```
$ meteor node --version
v4.8.4
```

As stated in [this issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/429), updating Node.js will help, but it's obviously can't be done with Meteor.

I suggest you to use [`sendgrid` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid), this one [works fine with Node.js v4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid#prerequisites).

Comment: Thanks - this might be the issue, although I'm not sure I understand what the underlying issue is...import/require should work in both node 4 and 6/8.  (if there was a direct version check, that would probably output a message indicating "version mismatch", no?)

Comment: @ASX The issue is in object destructuring, and [node 4 doesn't support that](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations-with-objects).

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this, and find it works fine.

```
import sendgridModule from 'sendgrid';

let SEND_GRID_API_KEY = '';
try {
  SEND_GRID_API_KEY = Meteor.settings.env.SEND_GRID_API_KEY;
} catch (e) {
  // no-op
}
const sendgrid = sendgridModule(SEND_GRID_API_KEY);
```

I think using `import` instead of `require` is preferred, and it now can be used for conditional imports

Comment: You should add `.valueOf()` to the end of the statement in the `try` block. This way you'll catch `undefined`/`null` values of `Meteor.settings.env.SEND_GRID_API_KEY`.

Comment: i think this works for sendgrid api v2, but in v3, they have split it into multiple modules. And the @sendgrid/mail module doesn't seem to have a named export (only a default one), if you look at code on github: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/mail